# CSV to sqlite import

Tags: python

Trying to import an existing csv into a table that will have blank elements but they're already allowed to have nulls and blanks.  It seems no matter which approach I take I get binding errors or a syntax error on the %s portion of the insert.  The Csv has four elements and does not include column headings.

```
import csv, sqlite3,sys

con = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
cur = con.cursor()

query="""INSERT INTO adm_Appointment(sch_time, operation_id, surgeon, 
pat_name)
VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"""


with open('dailypatientlist.csv','r') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
next(reader)
for line in reader:
    elements="line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3]"
    cur.execute(query,(elements,))

con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: Could we have an error message ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 15, in <module>
    cur.execute(query,(elements,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: @JeremyDePrato. The [relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) will show you that the required syntax is `VALUES(?,?,?,?)`.

Comment: that solved it ! thanks!